# Can anybody help me showing bullets and numbering when we render as pdf from visualforce

Tags: visualforce, pdf, css

Want to format description of all records and render as pdf.

Formatting includes,
Adding bullets and numbering,
Font color for description (other than red, yellow, blue, green colors).

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

```
CSS file:

    table{
                      border-collapse: collapse;

                      border: 1px solid green;
                      font-family: Cambria;
                      font-size:20px;
                      color:navy;
                  }

                        .bullets
                        {
                          list-style-type: circle;
                        }
    VF Page:
    <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <th>Monthly Report</th>
            </tr>
            <apex:repeat var="ctEvents" value="{!ctRecords}" >
                <tr border="0" Class="bullets">
                    <td><span style="list-style-type: disc;">{!ctEvents.Submitted_From__c}: <br/>{!ctEvents.Description__c}</span></td>
                    <div style="page-break-before:always;"> </div>
                </tr>
            </apex:repeat> 

        </table>
```

Comment: I think you've got the wrong site - here's the one you want: http://www.frelancers.com/

Comment: But seriously, this site is generally not used to get someone to write all your code. First, show us something you have written. Then, identify something that's not working for you (not the whole page please) and ask a question about how to resolve this particular issue. Used in this way, you will get good help and lots of it.

Comment: You'll need CSS for the colors. I'd recommend HTML for the rest of the formatting, with visualforce for any repeat sections or to link to an Apex class for logic.

Answer (score 1):

If you provide the code, it will be easier for us to help you.Based on my experience, some of css example table border,color need to define in the `<header>` tag.You can use css code for list and put it inside the header.

Try it first and let us know.